# How to expand/collapse items in peek reference window?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In peek reference window, I can use `C-n/C-p` move cursor down/up, but somehow I can't use `enter` key expand/collapse file items. Is there any way I can bind some key in peek reference window for it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can just left/right-arrow to collapse or expand those entries.  If you want to rebind those to something else, they are using the

`list.collapse`
`list.expand` commands.

You could try this keybinding:

```
{
  "key": "enter",
  "command": "list.toggleExpand",
  "when": "listFocus && editorId == 'vs.editor.ICodeEditor:1'"
},
```

so that <kbd>Enter</kbd> will toggle expand/close each reference list item.  I believe that `editorId == 'vs.editor.ICodeEditor:1'` is that particular list so that the command will only apply to the peek reference list, not all lists.